# WinRM Powershell commands not working

Tags: powershell, azure, winrm

I have an Azure VM which is running the Windows Remote Management (WinRM) service. I am trying to run below command in Powershell (run as admin) but getting an error.

```
winrm quickconfig
```

Error:

> Input Error: There is no script engine for file extension ".vbs"

In fact any WinRM related commands I try gives me the same error.

What could be the possible reasons for this error? Do I need to install an extension to make it run?

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: What OS is the VM running?  What resources have you checked already?  How was the OS provisioned (chef/puppet/manually) ?

Comment: It's running Windows Server 2012 OS and was provisioned manually

Comment: There are a couple of solutions proposed here, see if some of them matches your issue.

http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_xp-performance/error-there-is-no-script-engine-for-file-extension/ef023588-0c5c-4d37-a169-20eedb9c5a4c?auth=1

Comment: Thanks @proteus. I used the `assoc .vbs=VBSFile` command and was able to re-associate the `.vbs` extension to Microsoft ® Windows Based Script Host.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was that the .vbs extension was associated with the program Notepad++. And since winrm uses a vbs file to run it's commands, I did the following to re-associate the extension to Microsoft ® Windows Based Script Host.

1. Run command prompt as admin and execute below:

   assoc .vbs=VBSFile
2. Go to Control Panel -> Programs -> Default Programs -> Associate a file type or protocol with a specific program
3. Select .vbs extension -> click on Change Program -> Select Microsoft ® Windows Based Script Host

Thanks @proteus for the link which directed me to the solution.

Comment: Funny that Windows remote management configuration was written in vbs.  THAT needs an update.

Answer (score 0):

Run as admin on cmd:

```
regsvr32 vbscript.dll
```

Comment: Tried that, still getting same error.